# is there such thing a Bittorent passive tracking?

Tags: bittorrent

Hi I want to make an application that if given a torrent file (or hash) can give the number of peers without being active (i.e not responsible) in the process that allow the sharing of a file (for legal reason obviously). whether by being a "passive" (passive as define previously) tracker or a bittorrent client that counts "All time" peers (i.e. number of download for a torrent). Can it be done? I know some trackers keep track of download but I don't know if those who "seem not to" actually do as well. I look for something that can track the number of unique-ip transfers from when the torrent was added to the tracking system or something that count download (complete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to determine all peers just from a tracker. There can be multiple trackers for each torrent, and they may not store complete, fresh, or even truthful information. Additionally there's no obligation for peers to be honest with their trackers. There are also alternatives to centralized trackers, such as DHT and PEX. There's no guarantee that all peers are participating in the same DHT network. Peers might even establish disjoint PEX communities.

In short, you might make a best effort attempt at determining the total swarm participation for a particular torrent by checking trackers and querying DHT. But to be as thorough as the technology will allow, you'd actually have to participate in the swarm with all manner of transports and protocol extensions currently in use such as uTP and encryption, and scrape each peer for further peers and download states. Of course the BitTorrent community is familiar with such attempts to scrape data, and there a lot of security measures in place to prevent exploitation in this way. Examples include IP blocklists, and heuristics on peer behaviour.